Problem with cline being to short
I tried to build a Table which shows a multiclass confusion matrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
  \begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|c|c|c|}
      
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&  \multicolumn{5}{c}{PREDICTED CLASS}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{CLASS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$D   $   }\\\cline{3-7}
      \multirow{5}{*}{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ACTUAL CLASS}
      }} 
      
      &$A$& $TP_{A}$ & $E_{BA}$ &$E_{CA}$&$E_{DA}$  \\ \cline{3-7}
      &$B$&$E_{AB}$ & $TP_{B}$ &$E_{CB}$ &$E_{DB}$ \\  \cline{3-7}
      &$C$&$E_{AC}$& $E_{BC}$ &$TP_{C}$ &$E_{DC}$  \\ \cline{3-7}
      &$D$&$E_{D}$ & $E_{BD}$ &$E_{CD}$ &$TP_{D}$ \\ \cline{3-7} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

But like you can see in the picture my the cline ends to early so that there is this strange whitespace.

I hope you can help me to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. For this time, I have added the parts that are missing in any case, even if this only almost produces the result from your screenshot, the problem should be immediately reproducible.

It's easier to debug these things if you add a row with column numbers (just while testing)


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
  \begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|c|c|c|}
      1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&  \multicolumn{5}{c}{PREDICTED CLASS}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{CLASS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$D   $   }\\\cline{3-7}
      \multirow{5}{*}{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ACTUAL CLASS}
      }} 
      
      &$A$& $TP_{A}$ & $E_{BA}$ &$E_{CA}$&$E_{DA}$  \\ \cline{3-7}
      &$B$&$E_{AB}$ & $TP_{B}$ &$E_{CB}$ &$E_{DB}$ \\  \cline{3-7}
      &$C$&$E_{AC}$& $E_{BC}$ &$TP_{C}$ &$E_{DC}$  \\ \cline{3-7}
      &$D$&$E_{D}$ & $E_{BD}$ &$E_{CD}$ &$TP_{D}$ \\ \cline{3-7} 
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|c|c|}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&  \multicolumn{4}{c}{PREDICTED CLASS}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{CLASS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$D   $   }\\\cline{3-6}
      \multirow{5}{*}{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ACTUAL CLASS}
      }} 
      
      &$A$& $TP_{A}$ & $E_{BA}$ &$E_{CA}$&$E_{DA}$  \\ \cline{3-6}
      &$B$&$E_{AB}$ & $TP_{B}$ &$E_{CB}$ &$E_{DB}$ \\  \cline{3-6}
      &$C$&$E_{AC}$& $E_{BC}$ &$TP_{C}$ &$E_{DC}$  \\ \cline{3-6}
      &$D$&$E_{D}$ & $E_{BD}$ &$E_{CD}$ &$TP_{D}$ \\ \cline{3-6} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Thanks!
Great advice with the line for debugging. I started with the plan of having a 7th column for some formulas but forgot it.

For information, here is way to create that table with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{llcccc}
      & & \Block{1-4}{PREDICTED CLASS} \\
      \Block[l]{1-2}{CLASS} & & $A$ & $B$ & $C$ & $D$   \\
      \Block{4-1}{\rotate ACTUAL CLASS}
      & $A$ & \Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}
              $TP_{A}$ & $E_{BA}$ & $E_{CA}$ & $E_{DA}$ \\ 
      & $B$ & $E_{AB}$ & $TP_{B}$ & $E_{CB}$ & $E_{DB}$ \\  
      & $C$ & $E_{AC}$ & $E_{BC}$ & $TP_{C}$ & $E_{DC}$ \\ 
      & $D$ & $E_{D}$  & $E_{BD}$ & $E_{CD}$ & $TP_{D}$ \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


